# Is 'publish' an intransitive verb in this context?

Tags: verbs

This is from [*The Washington Post* article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/arts-entertainment/2022/04/10/johnny-depp-amber-heard-case/#O47DR7OJSFGTTDAPJDXIIHQFJI-1).

> The complaint states that Depp’s “reputation and career were
> devastated” after Heard’s first domestic violence accusation in 2016,
> but the op-ed “brought new damage”: Disney dropped Depp from the
> lucrative Pirates of the Caribbean franchise four days after **it**
> **published**.

I think the part in bold can be rewritten as 'it was published'.

Is 'publish' an intransitive verb in this context?

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but I've seen it a couple of times on CNN as well. I suspect it's journalese.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As what @Apollyon has mentioned in the comments, this is probably [Journalese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journalese), where it's a language regarded as a characteristic of the news style used in popular media. But yes, you can substitute it with "it was published", but both work here.